# Dynamic SQL Query in R (WHERE)

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I am trying out some dynamic SQL queries using R and the postgres package to connect to my DB.

Unfortunately I get an empty data frame if I execute the following statement:

```
    x <- "Mean"
query1 <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = paste(
  "SELECT *",
  "FROM name",
  "WHERE statistic = '",x,"'"))
```

I believe that there is a syntax error somewhere in the last line. I already changed the commas and quotation marks in every possible way, but nothing seems to work.
Does anyone have an idea how I can construct this SQL Query with a **dynamic WHERE Statement using a R variable**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    require(stringi)
    stri_paste("SELECT * ",
      "FROM name ",
      "WHERE statistic = '",x,"'",collapse="")
    ## [1] "SELECT * FROM name WHERE statistic = 'Mean'"
```

or use concatenate operator `%+%`

```
"SELECT * FROM name WHERE statistic ='" %+% x %+% "'"
## [1] "SELECT * FROM name WHERE statistic ='mean'"
```

Comment: The solution with the package "stringi" worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should use `paste0` instead of `paste` which is producing wrong results or `paste(..., collapse='')` which is slightly less efficient (see `?paste0` or [docs here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/paste.html)).

Also you should consider preparing your SQL statement in separated variable. In such way you can always easily check what SQL is being produced.

I would use this (and I am using this all the time):

```
  x   <- "Mean"
  sql <- paste0("select * from name where statistic='", x, "'")
  # print(sql)
  query1 <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

In case I have SQL inside a function I always add `debug` parameter so I can see what SQL is used:

```
function get_statistic(x=NA, debug=FALSE) {

  sql <- paste0("select * from name where statistic='", x, "'")

  if(debug) print(sql)

  query1 <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)

  query1
}
```

Then I can simply use `get_statistic('Mean', debug=TRUE)` and I will see immediately if generated SQL is really what I expected.

Answer (score 3):

**The Problem** The problem may be that you have spaces around `Mean`:

```
x <- "Mean"
s <- paste(
  "SELECT *",
  "FROM name",
  "WHERE statistic = '",x,"'")
```

giving:

```
> s
[1] "SELECT * FROM name WHERE statistic = ' Mean '"
```

**Corrected Version** Instead try:

```
s <- sprintf("select * from name where statistic = '%s'", x)
```

giving:

```
> s
[1] "select * from name where statistic = 'Mean'"
```

**gsubfn** You could also try this:

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * 
                    FROM name 
                    WHERE statistic = '$x'")
```

Comment: Ah! I didnt think of that! Do you have any clue how i can delete the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

A newer way to do this is with the `glue` package, part of the `tidyverse`. It is described as "An implementation of interpreted string literals, inspired by Python's Literal String Interpolation."

Using `glue`, you would do:

```
library(glue)
library(DBI)
x <- "Mean"
query1 <- glue_sql("
  SELECT *
  FROM name
  WHERE statistic = ({x})
  ", .con = con)
dbGetQuery(con, query1)
```

It's a great package due to its flexibility. For example, let's say you wanted to import mean, median and mode statistics. Then you would add an asterisk to the call like so:

```
x <- c("Mean", "Median", "Mode")
query2 <- glue_sql("
  SELECT *
  FROM name
  WHERE statistic = ({x*})
  ", .con = con)
dbGetQuery(con, query2)
```